# Unable to compile using Material-UI: Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/core-js/object/get-prototype-of'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, node-modules

I'm trying to use the CssBaseline component for my project from Material-UI, however ever since trying to figure out how to get it working, I am running into this error:

```
./node_modules/material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/core-js/object/get-prototype-of' in '.\node_modules\material-ui\styles'
```

Here's my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.7.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^3.0.0-alpha.4",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.47",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  }
```

Here's App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import NavBar from './components/header/NavBar';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Hero from './components/hero/Hero'
import './App.css';

const theme = createMuiTheme();

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <React.Fragment>    
          <CssBaseline />
          <NavBar />
          <Hero/>
        </React.Fragment>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the following two lines:

```
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

with:

```
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

and then remove the following dependencies:

```
"@material-ui/styles": "^3.0.0-alpha.4",
"material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.47",
```

and I would expect you'll be fine.